# Ant Target Clean is not executing

Tags: java, ant

I am new to Ant. To starting working with Ant I created one ant builder file build.xml.
Here is the sample file.

```
<path id="compile.classpath">
    <fileset dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>

<target name="init">
    <mkdir dir="build/classes"/>
    <delete dir="dist" />
    <mkdir dir="dist" />
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="init" >
    <javac destdir="build/classes" debug="true" srcdir="src" includeantruntime="false">
        <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="war" depends="compile">
    <war destfile="dist/abc.war" webxml="WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml">
        <fileset dir="WebContent"/>
        <lib dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib"/>
        <classes dir="build/classes"/>
    </war>
</target>

<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="dist" />
    <delete dir="build" />
</target>
```

Each target is running fine. My code is getting compiled, creating war file too, but last target named "clean" is not working. Ant is not showing any error message too.

**Ant Version**  - 1.7.1,
**java Version** - 1.6,
**OS** -  centos 6.5

Comment: What *is* it showing when you execute `ant -d clean`?

Comment: Or maybe you just have an view problem, just press F5 in Windows Explorer and check if they aren't deleted, because your build file looks fine.

Comment: @Andreas cleaning up process is running when I execute that command  as u suggested.But When I execute ant -file build.xml. in this case it is not working.

Comment: @Christian Thanks, but this thing I already tried.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run the clean target every time before creating war, change the init target as below:

```
<target name="init" depends="clean">
```

Comment: If I clean/delete all the folders before creating the war file then how war creation process will work ? From where it will get source code ?

Comment: In this case clean will run before all targets. After that init will create required folders.

Comment: if I wanna delete some folders at the end ?

Comment: You can have new default target as build                       <target name="build" depends="war">
    <delete dir="build" />
</target>

Comment: Can you please elaborate?